# Can access NAS by SSH in terminal but not through Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, ssh

I have a Synology DS411 and have SSH access through Terminal.

I've tried just about every walkthrough for how to connect to an SSH server in Nautilus but nothing has worked.

Any ideas why?

Is Nautilus using SFTP or something for it's SSH connections?

Come to mention it - I have tried setting up FTP connections to the server through Nautilus (I'm using Elementary if it matters) and it crashes after I enter the password.

I can use Filezilla with the same connection info fine. Not sure why it's a problem in Nautilus. Only reason I want to move on from Filezilla is very slow transfer speeds. I'm hoping the SSH would bring better results.

Comment: If you use Filezilla with SSH(SFTP) your speed is constant... I think the Nautilus won't transfer data faster...

Comment: Could you give some feedback on the answers you've received. Let the posters know if what they're suggesting doesn't work and they can improve their answers. Otherwise accept the best answer that works. Thank you!

Comment: You may review my answer, @AFD.

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu Desktop (Unity 3D, 2D)

To connect SSH hosted service with Nautilus, type in to the location bar this string:

`sftp://user@host[:port]` - SFTP means **SSH File Transfer Protocol**

The port is NOT necessary if it is the default **22**. You also can specify the dir, what you want to access: `sftp://user@host[:port][/my/data/dir]`

[image: nautilus connect to]

*(Image is illustration, from Nautilus 2 - its update sheduled)*

It will prompt for password.

[image: prompt for passwd]

---

### Ubuntu Classic (GNOME 2.x)

*Also you can use the **Connect to Server** function from the **Places** menu*...

(It may also available in Unity, by a search in Dash.)

[image: Select type of service]
[image: Connect to Server...]

*(Images are illustration.)*

---

*The **[]** are used to mark/express OPTIONAL information/data/string/etc.
Thanks for images to [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com).*

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sshfs`. 
You just create a directory on your local machine and then mount the remote share on it.

Like this:

```
sshfs user@IP:/ /mnt/directory/
```

A quick explanation of each part of the command:

- `sshfs` - this is the command for remote mounting a file system using ssh;
- `user@IP` - this would be the username you use for ssh and the IP of the NAS
- `:/` - this is the mount point on the NAS. You could always do something like `:/volume1/home` or just leave it as `:/` to mount it to the root
- `/mnt/directory` - this is the path to the directory on your local machine that you're mounting to.

So after doing this, you can browse the NAS through Nautilus like it was local.

Comment: Don't forget `-o allow_other` otherwise you can't access the mount dir as a regular user